# How to restore previous scroll position when coming back to fragment after navigating away

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have following project in Github : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/News-Cache

First that I load data in my Fragment, I display data from database, and start to load data from API. As soon as loading from API finished, I update the database and my recyclerView in Fragment get updated as well.

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.news.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<List<Article>> { articles ->
            articles?.apply {
                viewModelAdapter.submitList(articles)
            }
        })
    }
```

And this is my Adapter :

```
class NewsAdapter(val callback: OnClickListener) : ListAdapter<Article, NewsAdapter.NewsViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = NewsViewHolder.from(parent)

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NewsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position), callback)
    }

    /**
     * Allows the RecyclerView to determine which items have changed when the [List] of [Article]
     * has been updated.
     */
    companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.url == newItem.url
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

When new data arrives from API, I want to scroll to top of RecyclerView :

```
handler.postDelayed({
            binding.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)
        }, 1000)
```

The problem is when I go to Detail screen and navigate back to Main screen `onActivityCreated` and `onCreateView` get called and as a result `binding.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)` get called as well, which is not what I want.

What is the solution to scroll to top of RecyclerView when new data arrives from API?

Comment: so you want the recyclerview to stay at the same scroll position when you come back to it from another activity/fragment?

Comment: No I want to scroll to position 0 when new items arrive from API. While when I get back to main fragment, stay at same position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably solve this pretty easily by holding bool that will act as indicator .`isFirstLoad`

Set it to true in onActivityCreated just before you start observing news, then inside the observer set the action you'd like to do.

**Something like this should work:**

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        isFirstNewsFetch = true
        viewModel.news.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<List<Article>> { articles ->

            articles?.let { articles ->
                viewModelAdapter.submitList(articles)
                if(isFirstNewsFetch) {
                   isFirstNewsFetch = false
                 }else {
                  scrollToTop()
                 }
            }
        })
    }
```

**As a side note:**

`apply` standard function/scope function should be used for object configuration.

For your purpose use `let` - 
[Kotlin standard functions cheat sheet](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/kotlin-standard-functions-cheat-sheet-27f032dd4326)

Comment: When I start the app (create a new instance of application) `onActivityCreated ` called which means `scrollToTop()` never happen. I expect to move to top when start the app and new data arrives from API.

Comment: Aren't you already at the top when you start the app for the first time?

Comment: Yes(data from database), but then new data arrives from API in some seconds, and then I want to scroll to top.

Comment: The new data will trigger `scrollToTop` since `isFirstNewsFetch` is false. Maybe I don't fully understand what your saying.

Comment: I understood you point. Let me test and let you know. Thanks.